# Topological insulators literature

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, topological-order, topological-insulators

I started learning things on topological insulators and I got lost in dozens of existing papers on this topic. Could anyone recommend me appropriate literature that explains deeply enough what topological insulators are, how they are related to time-reversal symmetry issue, why the word "topological" is used, what a relation with Dirac fermions and oth. Any recommendations where I could start learning the topic from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think two great reviews on the topic (cited by almost any paper on the matter) are:

M. Z. Hasan and C. L. Kane, Colloquium: Topological insulators, Rev. Mod. Phys. 82, 3045 (2010);

X.-L. Qi and S.-C. Zhang, Topological insulators and superconductors, Rev. Mod. Phys. 83, 1057 (2011);

Answer (score 3):

There is a book on the topic:

B. Andrei Bernevig, Taylor L. Hughes: Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors, Princeton University Press (2013).

Comment: Can I download it from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There is this very nice and introductory paper from Soucheng Zhang published at Physics Today!

http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/magazine/physicstoday/article/63/1/10.1063/1.3293411

It exposes the basic concepts on TIs as well why they are interesting for future applications.

If you read that, please let me know if you liked It!

Cheers,
Graciely

Comment: Thanks Graciely for your suggestion. I will check this out and give my feedback to you.

Comment: Hi @Graciely! I've read the paper. It is really good a good introduction to the topological insulators and motivates to go further into details :)